# Using VBA to convert to XML, XML Schema is not applied consistently

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am using VBA to convert an Excel sheet to XML using working code as guide.

The header uses the following code:

```
Write xml header

a.Writeline ("<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>")

a.Writeline ("<eExact xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""eExact-Schema.xsd"">")

a.Writeline ("<GLEntries>")
```

code code code

ending with

```
a.Writeline (" </GLEntry>")

a.Writeline ("</GLEntries>")

a.Writeline ("</eExact>")

MsgBox ("XML file created")

a.Close
```

at the end.

In the existing file the XML looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE1Cb.jpg

In my new code I copied the existing code because the same needs to be applied but my XML looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHYHG.jpg

What causes this difference and how do I fix it.

I've looked at other files using the VBA to XML code and they all work.

I expect the schema to be applied but it isn't.

Comment: I think its all about the format of the file You saving this code, once I had similar issue and changed "Encoding" in the saving as window (saving again that not working file). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: You were right. It was saved as file and not as XML. 

Now problem two, it doesn't behave as expected anymore. Thank you for point me in the right direction for this problem!

Comment: What do You mean about that behaving?

Comment: When it's a file, no extension, it writes the code how it should look (I think) 
https://imgur.com/a/73MCEg4

when I add the xml extension it returns this
https://imgur.com/UNKIwS6

this is the header, entrydate entrydate, header, entrydate.. 

any idea why?

Comment: Looks like your browser instead of displaying you structure of xml code is displaying you output, if your code looks same as your base code you mention, maybe it's about view/display options in browser?
the only difference in your first 2 screenshots is the order of xsi:noname... and xmlns:xsi and the space before "?>" in first line. Maybe it is that?

Comment: hmm, don't think so.. the same browser displays the original code just fine.. 
when i gut the code (it has two while wend loops) and just ask for the header it works too
https://imgur.com/QJPJCik
When I add a while wend loop it gives me the partial output in a weird order..

Comment: Maybe try to seek there in the loop which is "destroying" everything. I got no other idea unfortunately.

Comment: You probably were right though, when opening the XML with notepad it shows the code. Thanks for everything :)